# 2D House Robber Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

This seems to be a variation of the LeetCode House Robber problem, but I found it significantly harder to tackle:

There are houses laid out on a NxN grid. Each house is known to contain some amount of valuables. The robbers task is to rob as many houses as possible to maximize the amount of loot. However there is a security system in place and if you rob two adjacent houses (to the left, right, above and below) an alarm will go off. Find the maximum loot the robber can rob.

```
      Houses   :  alignment
     10 20 10      0  1  0
     20 40 20  =>  1  0  1
     10 20 10      0  1  0

   This alignment results in the maximum of 80.
```

I've learned how to solve the optimum selection of houses for a single row with dynamic programming from https://shanzi.gitbooks.io/algorithm-notes/problem_solutions/house_robber.html:

```
public class HouseRobber {
    public int rob(int[] nums) {
        if (nums.length == 0) return 0;
        if (nums.length == 1) return nums[0];

        int[] dp = new int[nums.length];
        dp[0] = nums[0];

        int max = dp[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < dp.length; i++) {
            dp[i] = nums[i];
            // Do not need to check k < i - 3. 
            for (int j = 2; i - j >= 0 && j <= 3; j++) {
                dp[i] = Math.max(dp[i], dp[i - j] + nums[i]);
            }
            max = Math.max(dp[i], max);
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

But once I select one row's optimum selection, it might not align with with the optimum selections for the rows above and below that row. Even if I find the optimum combination for two rows, the next row might have more valuables than the two rows combined and would require another adjustment, and on and on.

This is difficult because there are a lot more variables to consider than houses on a single row and there could also be more than one optimum alignments that give the robber maximum loot (such as the example above.)

I did find what seemed to be a poorly written solution in Python, but since I only understand C-based languages (Java, C#, C++), I couldn't get much out of it. Could anyone help me with a solution or at least some pointers?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I honestly don't see any other way of doing this that's not brute force. I think you really need to get all valid grid combinations, i.e. with no adjacent houses, and take the one(s) that give you the max value.

Comment: So go through every single combination possible? How about these solutions: https://pastebin.com/Lpu5f6KA or https://pastebin.com/tBqWRPQG. I don't know Python, but I was wondering if the logic had any merit to consider.

Comment: When one of the dimensions is short enough, dynamic programming by profile will help (sadly no definitive link but [at least something](https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic+programming+by+profile)). The basic idea is as follows: for each mask corresponding to a row, transfer to all possible masks corresponding to the next row. It is exponential in one dimension, but if your board was like 10x1000 instead of NxN, this would be the preferred method.

Comment: Is this problem online for submission?

Comment: Do you have a link for me to submit my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I went through the [python](https://pastebin.com/tBqWRPQG) code you mentioned. The solution using flow looks plain wrong to me. There is no path from source to sink with finite weight. That solution basically colors the grid like a chessboard and chooses either all the black squares or all the white squares. That is not optimal in the following case:

```
1     500
300   1
1000  300
```

It is better to choose 1000 and 500 but that solution will choose 300+300+500.

The dynamic programming solution is exponential.
I don't know enough math to understand the LP solution.

Sorry to not answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for going through the python code! At this point I am trying to approach the problem brute force, but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: This is why I said why I don't see any other way than brute force. You can probably optimize a bit by using memoization (caching the results of what you've already computed). But when you talk about "max" something, you either have some very specific pre-arranged data, or you have to go through all of it.

Comment: @juvian I just saw that CDLee posted two links to python code. I looked at [this](https://pastebin.com/tBqWRPQG) one. Did you run the other one or this?

Comment: I run the one you linked on your answer, maybe you linked the wrong one then

Comment: Oops I put the wrong link. I am going to edit my answer.

Comment: The solution in the other link is exponential.